# PS+ server question

Tags: playstation-plus

I live in Mongolia, where I am unable to access the Playstation Network. I have a relative living in the UK, and I recently purchased a UK PS4 from there and shipped to me here. If I open a PS+ account registered as UK from here, does that automatically connect me to EU servers while playing online? Is it possible to connect to Asian servers even though you have a UK PS+?

Comment: Why are you unable to access the PSN? I am not really sure how getting a PS4 sent from the UK will help you with that, if you couldn't access it before I'm not sure what would change.

Comment: This question title should be edited.

Answer (score 1):

The region of your PS+ account doesn't really have any bearing on regional matchmaking for online games. It actually depends on the game itself, as Sony  leaves it up to the game companies to implement their own matchmaking systems.

Some games actually have a matchmaking browser that lets you choose which server you'd like to play on but most handle it automatically. As a general rule of thumb your IP location is what their systems use to determine which geographic locations to match you up with and which servers you're closest to. It really just depends on how the designers of a given game decided they want to handle the matchmaking for it.